# How to add ones to matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have an array:

```
X = [[2, 2, 2],
     [3, 3, 3],
     [4, 4, 4]]
```

I need to add extra column in numpy array and fill it with ones using hstack and reshape. Like that:

```
X = [[2, 2, 2, 1],
     [3, 3, 3, 1],
     [4, 4, 4, 1]]
```

What I do:

```
X = np.hstack(X, np.ones(X.reshape(X, (2,3))))
```

And a get an error:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

What's a problem? What I've done wrong?

Comment: Try `np.column_stack`.

Comment: The problem is in the `np.ones()` call.  You gave it an array, not a tuple of dimensions.  Experiment with that alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a couple ways with `numpy.append`, `numpy.hstack` or `numpy.column_stack`:

```
# numpy is imported as np
>>> x
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]])
>>> np.append(x, np.ones([x.shape[0], 1], dtype=np.int32), axis=1)
array([[2, 2, 2, 1],
       [3, 3, 3, 1],
       [4, 4, 4, 1]])
>>> np.hstack([x, np.ones([x.shape[0], 1], dtype=np.int32)])
array([[2, 2, 2, 1],
       [3, 3, 3, 1],
       [4, 4, 4, 1]])
>>> np.column_stack([x, np.ones([x.shape[0], 1], dtype=np.int32)])
array([[2, 2, 2, 1],
       [3, 3, 3, 1],
       [4, 4, 4, 1]])
```

Comment: Thanks timgeb. You use shape. Solve this question using reshape can't be real?

Comment: @AlexSavin reshaping will return a new array with a new shape, I don't think that would be too helpful as you can't change the total size of the array with reshaping.

Comment: @timggeb Ok, that realization add ones column to the end of matrix (np.hstack...). But how add ones column to the begining of matrix?

Comment: @AlexSavin just switch the order of the arguments, i.e. `np.hstack([np.ones([x.shape[0], 1], dtype=np.int32), x])`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `numpy.insert()`:

```
>>> X
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]])
```

Ones at the begining of matrix:

```
>>> X=np.insert(X,0,1.0,axis=1)
>>> X
array([[1, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 4, 4, 4]])
```

Ones at the end of matrix

```
>>> X=np.insert(X,3,1.0,axis=1)
>>> X
array([[2, 2, 2, 1],
       [3, 3, 3, 1],
       [4, 4, 4, 1]])
```